# Magento 2 Access REST API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, integration

I tried looking for answers before posting but couldn't find any.

I hosted my magento site in siteground and added integration.

Then I tried accessing the API using Postman but I get either 401 error or could not get any response.

Can someone help me with this?

[image]

UPDATED:
Turns out the problem is on the hosting site. Tried accessing on localhost and its working. But when I tried accessing in my host server I got 401. Any idea? I'm using siteground for hosting my magento.

Comment: you might want to rotate your credentials as your tokens are now public via your screenshot

Comment: @KristofatFooman its okay its still under construction. So no data for now. Might do it after fixing the issue.

Comment: here is the video about rest api access levels https://youtu.be/9OpjTwifhaE

Comment: did you find any solution? because the same issue occur from my side and same hosting i used right now.

Answer (score 1):

> **If you are using token-based authentication,** create a web services user on Magento Admin by selecting System > Permission > All Users >
>   Add New User. (If you are using session-based or OAuth authentication,
>   you do not need to create the new user in the Admin.)
>
> **Create a new integration on Magento Admin**. To create an integration, click System > Extensions > Integration > Add New
>   Integration. Be sure to restrict which resources the integration can
>   access.
>
> Use a REST or SOAP client to configure authentication.

**Sample code snippet to check in postman**

```
API Endpoint : magento_host_url/rest/V1/products/types

Method : GET

Headers:
**Key**                  **value**
Content-type :   application/json
Authorization :  Bearer youraccesstoken  

(here you need to place your Access Token which you get from System > Extensions > Integration > Edit.)
```

Response you will get is like below :

```
[
    {
        "name": "simple",
        "label": "Simple Product"
    },
    {
        "name": "virtual",
        "label": "Virtual Product"
    },
    {
        "name": "configurable",
        "label": "Configurable Product"
    },
    {
        "name": "downloadable",
        "label": "Downloadable Product"
    },
    {
        "name": "grouped",
        "label": "Grouped Product"
    },
    {
        "name": "bundle",
        "label": "Bundle Product"
    }
]
```

Please find below screenshot for more information.
[image]

If above code is working or useful for you then upvote the answer and mark the answer as accepted so that other users can easily identify the answer.

Comment: I'm using the session-based and tried your answer but no luck.
I tried this.

API Endpoint: https://www.splashm2.sg-host.com/rest/V1/products/types

Method: GET

Headers:
**Key**                  **value**
Content-type :   application/json
Authorization :  Bearer myaccesstoken  

But still no luck.

Comment: I think this is not from magento. I think this issue is caused by the siteground. Because I tried calling the API from my local and its was a success. But when I tried called it from siteground host, it gave me 401 error.

Comment: it is working in default magento i have cross verified with 2-3 instances, if you are facing issue with service provider then do contact them might be there are restrict some external API calls or some ports may be disable in your server. i have edited my answer with working screenshot for reference.